# PHP script wont run on scueduled task (Windows 7)

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

Attempting to run a php script to update a database every hour with windows 7 Task Scheduler. The File updates when i open it up as a webpage but does not update when i run it from task scheduler . Under the trigger tab I have it set to run daily, and then repeat the task every hour for a duration of indefinetly. Under actions I have it set to Start Program. And the link to my file as C:\Users\jmac\Desktop\testdbconnection.php 
Additionally under Start in box I have C:\Users\E15913\Desktop
I have no coditions that should be blcoking it from running. In addition when I test run the file it says it is completed succefully but the database is not updated. I will also post the code below, which once again works when I refresh it or pull it up in a web browser.

```
<?php
// Did modify login values for privacy
$servername = "10.100.";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "abc123";
$dbname = "informationdata";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$file = fopen("ALMGrade.csv","r");

while(! feof($file)){

 $ar =fgetcsv($file);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO gradetable_copy (Grade, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5, Grade6)
VALUES ('$ar[0]', '$ar[1]', '$ar[2]', '$ar[3]', '$ar[4]', '$ar[5]', '$ar[6]' )";
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";\
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
fclose($file);






$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: are you sure that your file "ALMGrade.csv" is reachable ? print something when `if(!$file) {}`

Comment: Is it working when you call your script directly from command prompt? Don't you maybe have to call it as "php testdbconnection.php" (sorry, if my question is dumb - didn't used php under windows OS)?

Comment: @Halayem Yes I just tried that and it works, I moved both files to a folder on my desktop so they are in the same place.

Comment: @MilanG I also tried running it from cmd and it did not update either. I tried calling it as php testdbconnection.php and it is invalid.

Comment: So it's not a scheduler problem, but PHP problem. Did you even installed PHP?